# Autocomplete dropdown generates unwanted keydown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On my website I have several input fields in a form.  I want the user to be able to submit the form on any of the fields by hitting the enter key.  However, this causes an issue because in Internet Explorer and Safari if the user types a few letters and an autocomplete dropdown opens and they use arrow keys and hit enter to do the autocomplete, the form will submit.

How can I change this behavior?

Also note that I have a custom function for "submitting".  It is not the default submit.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$('.submitButton').click( submitContactForm );

$('.column input, .submitButton').keydown(function( e ){
    if( e.keyCode == 13 ){// if 'enter' key
        $('.submitButton').click();
    }
});
```

Comment: To clarify, I am not talking about an autocomplete plugin, I am talking about native browser autocomplete suggestion dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to use the [safeEnter jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SafeEnter).  Looks like it will solve this problem nicely.

Answer (score 0):

you need add **onkeydown** event on dropdown of autocomplete and return false in function.

Comment: It's the built in browser autocomplete dropdown.  It is not in my code.

Comment: You tell about default form's submit?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to prevent form from submitting, you should call `preventDefault()` method on the event object in the event Handler.

```
element.onkeydown = function(event){
   var event = event || window.event;
   event.preventDefault();
   var code = event.keycode || event.which;

   if(code === 13){
    // Your enter behavior
   }
}
```

you can prevent event from bubbling up the DOM by calling `event.stopPropagation();`. if your autocomplete is the somewhere in your form this will help not to fire the event on the form but only on autocomplete.

Comment: I want it to submit on enter.  I just don't want it to submit when the enter keypress is in an autocomplete dropdown.